# Is there a way in Azure to add an existing virtual machine to a virtual network without deleting/recreating?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Can I add existing virtual machine to virtual network?
I have seen this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2013/05/29/moving-a-virtual-machine-from-one-virtual-network-to-another.aspx

and it asks to unattach disk and delete and then create new virtual machine.

Which is impossible in production environment vm.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you can open a ticket to support team do that for you, but I'm afraid that there's no other option besides this one you found.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to change vNet of VM and NOT storage and Location ?  If yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, no other option for time being (2014-09-05).

As already suggested, you may try with opening a support ticket, but I doubt that would also help. Before all, Virtual Networks are associated with Affinity Groups. An absolute requirement is that the VHD for the VM uses storage account in the `same Affinity Group` as the Virtual Network, as well as the Cloud Service that hosts the VM should be also in the same Affinity Group.

To conclude, you have slight chance to solve the issue with support ticket if your new VM and its VHDs are in the same Affinity Group as the Virtual Network. If they are not (either the VM or the VHDs), then your only option is delete and recreate.